# How do I format dictionary Key and Values using format()

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python newbie here, using Python 2.7. I'm creating a program that prints out a random recipe with its ingredients and instructions. I'll post my code at the end. The output I'm getting is:

> Here is a recipe('Sushi', ['tuna', 'rice', 'mayonnaise', 'wasabi'])
>
> 1. Wash off the tuna

But I want this:

> Here is a recipe: Sushi: tuna, rice, mayonnaise, wasabi
>
> 1. Wash off the tuna

Can I use the format() method to accomplish something like this?

Here is my code:

```
import random

def random_recipe():
    recipe_dict = {'ChocolateCake':['flour', 'eggs', 'chocolate', 'oil', 'frosting'],
                   'Pasta':['noodles', 'marinara','onions'],
                   'Sushi':['tuna','rice','mayonnaise','wasabi']}


    print "Here is a recipe" + str(random.choice(list(recipe_dict.items())))

    if recipe_dict.keys() == 'ChocolateCake':
        print "1. Mix the flour with the eggs"
    elif recipe_dict.keys() == 'Pasta':
        print "1. Boil some water"
    else:
        print "1. Wash off the tuna"
```

Comment: Something to note is that this will always print `1. Wash off the tuna` regardless of recipe because `recipe_dict.keys() == ['Pasta', 'Sushi', 'ChocolateCake']` and will never be either of the things in the or elif.

Comment: Thank you @timotree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are retrieving tuple from random, Find the below working code

```
import random

recipe_dict = {'ChocolateCake':['flour', 'eggs', 'chocolate', 'oil', 'frosting'],
               'Pasta':['noodles', 'marinara','onions'],
               'Sushi':['tuna','rice','mayonnaise','wasabi']}


ra_item = random.choice(list(recipe_dict.items()))
print  "Here is a recipe {}:{}".format(ra_item[0],','.join(ra_item[1]))

if recipe_dict.keys() == 'ChocolateCake':
    print "1. Mix the flour with the eggs"
elif recipe_dict.keys() == 'Pasta':
    print "1. Boil some water"
else:
    print "1. Wash off the tuna"
```

You will get the expected output with this code.

Comment: Thank you. What does the 'join' method do in Python?

Comment: It's actually a string function. It will take the values inside the iterable(list in your case) and join with the character which you mention inside the quotes. Give a upvote if you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `join()` to join your dict's values like this example:

```
from random import choice

recipe_dict = {'ChocolateCake':['flour', 'eggs', 'chocolate', 'oil', 'frosting'],
                   'Pasta':['noodles', 'marinara','onions'],
                   'Sushi':['tuna','rice','mayonnaise','wasabi']}

# Or you can unpack your data:
# key, val = choice(recipe_dict.items())
keys = list(recipe_dict.keys())
random_key = choice(keys)
# Using str.format()
print "Here is a recipe: {}: {}".format(random_key, ', '.join(recipe_dict[random_key]))

if random_key == 'ChocolateCake':
    print "1. Mix the flour with the eggs"
elif random_key == 'Pasta':
    print "1. Boil some water"
else:
    print "1. Wash off the tuna"
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `a` with your `recipe_dict` in the code below:

```
for k, v in a.items():
    print( k + ': ' + ','.join(map(str, v)))
```